# Does EXE or DLL own moved memory?

Tags: c++, windows

In Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017, I have an EXE that loads a DLL dynamically, at runtime. They're both written in C++.

Once the DLL is loaded, the EXE calls a factory function in the DLL. This factory function returns a std::unique_ptr < T >.

```
// Function in the DLL.
std::unique_ptr<T> factory() {
   return std::make_unique<DerivedT>();
}
```

**Once the EXE receives the std::unique_ptr, where does this memory reside? is it in the DLL's heap or in the EXE's heap? Can the DLL be safely unloaded and the EXE keeps the memory and refer to this memory afterwards?**

I've done a simple test (within a larger program) and it seems like I can unload the DLL without losing the memory (I only keep it for a short time). Though, I'm not sure if I've just gotten lucky, and this is actually illegal to do.

Comment: Well.. afaik, any memory allocated by the DLL needs to be freed by the DLL.. but if that unique_ptr is "moved" into the Application's memory, but was allocated by the DLL then it crosses the boundaries since the destructor will be called in the application but the memory pointer would have been allocated by the DLL.. Afaik, this should never be done unless they use the same compiler and ABI, etc.. Perhaps it "might" work with a custom deleter..

Comment: *is it in the DLL's heap or in the EXE's heap* -- Passing C++ objects across executable boundaries is wrought with issues.  One is that if the object handles dynamically allocated memory, the DLL and EXE should be sharing the same heap.  You can see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279052/c-passing-stdstring-by-reference-to-function-in-dll) concerning `std::string`.

Comment: Your question "Where does this memory reside?" is ambiguous. There are two pieces of memory. One for the `unique_ptr` and one for the `DerivedT` inside the `unique_ptr`. Note also that C++ library objects are not a stable ABI. Passing them between modules requires that the modules be using the same version of the compiler and library.

Comment: In my case, it is guaranteed that both the EXE and the DLL will be build with the same, exact, compiler. Also, both are using the Visual Studio "Multi-threaded [Debug] DLL" runtime, so they should be sharing the same heap. Based on the answer that @PaulMckenzie linked, it sound like this is legal to do.

Comment: @ray: The same version of the library is not sufficient. They need to use the same copy.

Comment: Presumably, `DerivedT` is implemented in the DLL. In that case you cannot unload the DLL until all instances handed out by the module have been destroyed. While you probably aren't going to run into any issues in your specific scenario, you might want to consider using a system that provides a stable ABI. A COM server or a Windows Runtime component would work reliably, across different compilers, support libraries and OS versions.

Comment: This used to be quite risky in the olden days, you needed to ensure that the exe and dll modules used the exact same version of the C runtime library.  Building with /MD was a hard requirement, but the compiler version mattered as well.  So the modules use the same msvrxxx.dll version.  But VS2012 had a massive change, the CRT now allocates from the default process heap instead of creating its own heap.  Reflected also in Win8, no distinction anymore between HeapAlloc and CoTaskMemAlloc.  WinRT was the probable inspiration for those changes.  So much better odds that this works today.