# Error when releasing memory of std::vector container in UE4

Tags: c++, opencv, unreal-engine4

I want to detect doors from webcam data in **UE4** (ver.4.27.2) by loading **YOLO** in **OPENCV** (ver.4.55). My OPENCV plugin for UE4 can call the webcam as well as perform some image processing algorithms successfully. So I think there should be no problem with the plugin itself. My OPENCV code was migrated to Unreal Engine only after successful external testing. **But when I use the DNN module from OPENCV in unreal, I always get the following error:**

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAFB82551B (UE4Editor-Core.dll) in UE4Editor-Win64-DebugGame.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000010.
```

**The code related to my  minimal reproducible example is shown below:**

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

vector<int> outLayers = vector<int>();
vector<String> layersNames = vector<String>();

void FindVerticesProcess()
{
// Line 1310 to 1339
VideoCapture cap;
string srcPath = "E:\\project\\CornerDetector\\src\\";
String videoPath = srcPath + string("IMG_3436.mov");
String modelConfiguration = srcPath + string("yolo-fastest-1.1.cfg");
String modelWeights = srcPath + string("yolo-fastest-1.1_best.weights");
String classesFile = srcPath + string("yolo-fastest-1.1.names");

    cv::dnn::Net doorNet;
    vector<string> classes;
    ifstream ifs(classesFile.c_str());
    string line;
    while (getline(ifs, line)) {
        classes.push_back(line);
    }
    doorNet = cv::dnn::readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelWeights);
    doorNet.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV);
    doorNet.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_OPENCL);
    cap.open(videoPath);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Mat frame;
        cap.read(frame);
        Mat blob;
        cv::dnn::blobFromImage(frame, blob, 1 / 255.0, cv::Size(320, 320));
        doorNet.setInput(blob);
        outLayers.resize(0);
        layersNames.resize(0);
        outLayers = doorNet.getUnconnectedOutLayers();
        layersNames = doorNet.getLayerNames();
    }

}
```

**The call stack info:**

```
    UE4Editor-Core.dll!00007ffafb82551b()   Unknown
    UE4Editor-Core.dll!00007ffafb826a3e()   Unknown
    UE4Editor-Core.dll!00007ffafb829eb3()   Unknown
    UE4Editor-Core.dll!00007ffafb37893c()   Unknown
    UE4Editor-OpenCV-Win64-DebugGame.dll!operator delete(void * Ptr, unsigned __int64 Size) Line 26 C++
    [External Code] 

> UE4Editor-OpenCV-Win64-DebugGame.dll!FindVerticesProcess() Line 1338  C++
> UE4Editor-OpenCV-Win64-DebugGame.dll!FFindVertices::Run() Line 1412   C++
> [External Code]
```

According to the result of the call stack, if I understand correctly the problem is caused when the memory is freed in `doorNet.getLayerNames()`. However, during the for-loop test, I found that this error does not appear in a fixed location, and both `doorNet.getUnconnectedOutLayers()` and `doorNet.getLayerNames()` have the probability to trigger this error. I find that in most cases the first loop in the for-loop triggers this error. But sometimes the first loop is runnable and the error doesn't occur until the second or third loop. This situation is rather random. **The error disappears after I delete `outLayers = doorNet.getUnconnectedOutLayers();` and `layersNames = doorNet.getLayerNames();`**.

**I have found a similar problem here:**

[Exception deallocating memory for std::string (trying to use YOLO/Darknet inside UE4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60623053/exception-deallocating-memory-for-stdstring-trying-to-use-yolo-darknet-inside)

But I did not find any useful solusion in this webpage. Because `doorNet.getUnconnectedOutLayers()` and `doorNet.getLayerNames()` are both from OPENCV, I cannot rewritten them to only use raw C types in them.

So how can I fix this error?

Comment: The address `0x0000000000000010` looks very much like someone trying to access something 16 bytes off a nullptr.

Comment: Since this error is caused by some random memory corruption the best way to resolve is to start slowly removing code. When the error goes away the last piece of code removed was (probably) responsible for the error.

Comment: The error disappears after I delete `outLayers = doorNet.getUnconnectedOutLayers();` and `layersNames = doorNet.getLayerNames();`. But I just don't know why these two line cause this error. They are copied from OPENCV's offical tutorial.

Comment: I find that in most cases the first loop in the for-loop triggers this error. But sometimes the first loop is runnable and the error doesn't occur until the second or third loop. This situation is rather random.

Comment: I have not used UE, but this: `Mat frame; Mat blob;` creates local variables that will be destroyed on every loop iteration.  Is this your intent?

Comment: I moved both Mat's outside the loop body, but got the same error.